# repeater rebind and code on apsx page

Tags: asp.net

Im using repeater to display userPhotos. For loggedIn user photos I would like to have deleteButton visible and for the rest no.

Everything is ok on the first Load.

code for Visible works ok:

```
Visible='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId").ToString() == LoggedUser.ToString() %>"
```

but on the PostBack even though the same data is binded to the repeater code:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId").ToString() == LoggedUser.ToString() %>"
```

always returns false.

Why is it like taht ?

I have also printed

```
 <%= LoggedUser.ToString() %>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId").ToString() %>
```

and both texts are the same in both ways (with postback and without - on first page load.

Any suggestions ?

The backcode is:

```
private void LoadUserPhoto(int pageNumber)
{

    LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager();
    int loginId = loginManager.getLoggedP();

    UserPhoto userPhoto = new UserPhoto();
    List<Photo> photos = userPhoto.GetUserPhotos(loginId.ToString(), pageNumber, pageSize);

        rptrImages.DataSource = photos;
        rptrImages.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And on PageLoad i have only:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   LoadUserPhoto(0);
}
```

and on buttonClick handler the same code:

```
LoadUserPhoto(0);
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code-behind for this functionality? Most likely it is a re-binding problem, but hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: has one got some whitespace that you can't see when printing out maybe. Would stop a match

Comment: I added Trim() with no result

Comment: Ok Problem solved, i Was updating Property LoggedUser in wrong moment, thanks for help

Comment: Try to put the logic in the ItemDataBound event of the repeater, this way you have more control over and you can see what's happening.